# Can't get Google Sheet Data, but other attributes are avelible

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-sheets

I'm just try to fetch my test [spreadsheet's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R6oPLXnONWqo88Mg4WeQXW6yyzMnPOuO1jjYospyt6k/edit?usp=sharing)(API v4) sheets' data by this way:

```
var service = new SheetsService(
    new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = new Credentials().Data,
        ApplicationName = Config.AppName
    });

var request = service.Spreadsheets.Get(sheet_id);
var response = request.Execute();
var sheets = response.Sheets;

foreach (var sheet in sheets)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sheet.Data.GetType());
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
    }
}
```

It throws `NullReferenceException`, but if I replace `Data` by another attribute(*e.g.* `Properties`, `Merges`) it works correctly.
In a nutshell it fails only on `Data` attribute.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Surely, I can fetch every sheet`s data by single request, but... You understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get), you need to add includeGridData=true to the URL parameters if you want to include all data.

The C# wrapper you are using exposes this property on the SpreadsheetsResource.GetRequest:

```
var request = service.Spreadsheets.Get(sheet_id);
request.IncludeGridData = true; // <-- This will include the grid data
var response = request.Execute();
```